# Dynamic routes but not in the traditional sense

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I wanted to know if there is a way to dynamically generate routes based on data from a database?

Currently, i am defining my routes in a routes file and then importing that into my vue project. Is there a way i can have specific configurations stored on a database such as the path, name, meta data and then when the application loads, depending on the auth level of the user, create routes for that user?

Reason why I'm asking to create and not use a pre-written route with params is because i want to give my users (at some point in the future) the ability to create their own pages from my system.

So just wanted to know from the community if there is a way to do this based on an axios call or something?

Comment: If you are new to vue, let me help you understand routes better, ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Comment: @Syed Thanks for the offer but not i'm not completely new, learning off Udemy

Answer (score 0):

You can just use dynamic routing. To create new templates, code must be changed anyway.

Comment: Was hoping it would not lead to this and that there would be a way to make things self adaptive without digging immensely deep into it. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think technically you are still better off using a `title` parameter with a common prefix and just looking up that title. In theory it sounds nice to have a completely dynamic application where anyone can create any page... until someone decides to use "login" as the page name and override your own login component, making the app unusable.

That said, you can use [`router.addRoutes`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes) to dynamically add routes to your router. Create a router with the static routes (e.g. your homepage, your login page, your 404 page), then extend your router based on an api call.

Comment: I didn't even realize that a method like that existed, i think that accurately solves my issue but will need to test to see if it's worth using that rather than defined routes with varying params